Testing Ubuntu beta
I want to start testing Ubuntu beta, but I don't want to download a new iso every time so I am using rsync.  How do I use it to sync my local copy of the ubuntu iso with the ubdated on on the server. I use this command rsync -n rsync://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/20240419.2/noble-desktop-amd64.iso noble-desktop-amd64.iso, but I get this error.
@ERROR: Unknown module 'daily-live'
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1863) [Receiver=3.2.7]


Why not use zsync  which updates the current ISO and only downloads the changes... Either way the development release is off-topic here, but thank you for testing.  FYI:  The beta ISO was a single image dated 20240410.2 (ie. 10 April 2nd spin), but current daily is 20240420 or 10 days later... The beta ISO is a specific daily that gets labelled beta, ISOs are not created for ~3 days then re-start..  You want the latest daily not the older beta

Update the beta version
Updating the beta version of Ubuntu will download and install the updates. There is no need for installing from new ISO everyday.
You can do this by opening a terminal and entering two commands:
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

Please note that bug reports and issues with the beta versions are off topic here. See How do I report a bug? for how to report bugs.
Stable release
When the final version is generally available, the same update/upgrade process will convert the beta to the GA version.
Hope this helps

Recent changes in t64 transition requires sudo apt full-upgrade to automatically remove the old packages and replace them with t64 dependencies. Running sudo apt upgrade results in packages being held back.

Thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi. I have edited the answer.

Thank you, I am using the Ubuntu ISO tracker. When I try to use the rsync command I get this error: @ERROR: Unknown module 'daily-live'
